# "'WebForm_DoCallback' não está definido" - IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Tive um problema num site que estou programando ao executá-lo no IE11.

Após colocar a tag  dentro da minha  para que o código seja emulado no como IE 9:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Estava tudo funcionando até chegar na função de Callback:

```
function CallServer(arg, context) {WebForm_DoCallback('__Page',arg,retornoCallback,"",erroCallback,true); }
```

E é exibida a mensagem:`'WebForm_DoCallback' não está definido`

Como fazer que o código execute normalmente?

Comment: Onde você está declarando a função `WebForm_DoCallback()` ? poderia mostrar o código dela? Provavelmente há erros de sintaxe nela, ou ela não está sendo declarada.

Comment: @bigown o interessante é que rodando localmente ele funciona perfeitamente mas não no serivdor. E notei também que se trocar o user-agent do IE 11 para IE 9 (além do document type) ele funciona sem problemas. Infelizmente não posso mostrar trecho de código. OBS: essa função roda sem problemas em outros navegadores.

Answer (score 1):

É possível que seja um problema [já conhecido](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) com o IIS/Asp.Net do servidor, onde a Microsoft fornece alguns hotfixes ([download aqui](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)) que afetam o servidor de maneira geral e todas as aplicações, ou uma package do Nuget ([App_BrowsersUpdate](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/App_BrowsersUpdate)) para resolução do problema em uma única aplicação.

O Scott Hanselman tem um excelente [artigo](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) explicando melhor sobre essas soluções (no caso dele o problema ocorria na função __doPostback(), mas a idéia é a mesma)

Comment: instalei a atualização no servidor e nada aconteceu.